# Custom View MediaController

Tags: java, android

Собственно такой вопрос, как поставить свой Layout в MediaController?
Мне MediaController нужен для проигрывания только Аудио и мне хотелось бы добавить кнопку "Повторять" и другие несколько кнопок, а также названия проигрываемого файла, собственный Layout решил бы эту проблему, но сколько перерыл в интернете, но простого решения, заменить стандартный Layout на свой не нашел.

Comment: Создайте свою разметку и повесьте на неё свою логику...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а можно ли не переписывать методы SeekBar и другие методы, оставив их методами по умолчанию, при этом использовав свой Layout? Нужно обозначить на своей разметке, такие же id как и на оригинальной?